# Mybatis-spring-boot - cant use datasource that was injected as bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

below is my configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@Component
class Config {
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.spring.datasource")
public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() {

    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}

}
```

I am using Spring boot and spring-boot-mybatis-starter.   My `application.properties` file is properly completed.  Keep in mind, that I follow  this:  http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/

However, during launching I get error:

```
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'spring.datasource.type'
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager'
```

Can you help me, please ?

When I excluce `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` then I get:

```
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager'
```

When I drop datasource bean and remove prefix `my.` in all  datasouece properties everything is ok.

**Edit**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method sqlSessionTemplate in org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'sqlSessionFactory' in 'MybatisAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'sqlSessionFactory'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory' in your configuration.
```

**application.properties**

```
my.spring.datasource.driverClassName=***
my.spring.datasource.url=****
my.spring.datasource.username=user
my.spring.datasource.password=****
my.spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

Comment: Why are you configuring your own datasource? Why not use the one provided by Spring Boot based on the `spring.datasource` properties? Also the messages aren't about YOUR datasource as yu should have properties named `my.spring.datasource.whatever` in your configuration. Also `@Configuration` shouldn't be annotated with `@Component`.

Comment: *Why are you configuring your own datasource?* Since, I am going to define Routed Dynamic datasource (and give it to mybatis and be able to choose database).    *Also the messages aren't about YOUR datasource as yu should have properties named my.spring.datasource.whatever in your configuration* I think so, however no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to fix anything... Those message are for the default datasource which you don't configure.

Comment: But application doesn't start by these errors

Comment: No those aren't errors. Those are matches and negative matches NOT errors... Your mistake lies else where and has nothing to do with the default datasource. However as stated your `@Configuration` shouldn't be a `@Component`.

Comment: Ok, but it should be `@Component` - after all there are should be created beans. I made some progress:  `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MybatisAutoConfiguration.class})`
give following effect:  Now I get other error: `Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required`.   Could you help me ?

Comment: No it shouldn't... an `@Configuration` is  special `@Component` it should be `@Configuration`. Just randomly disabling auto configuration classes isn't going to help you any further. Also instead on focussing on the wrong things focus on what isn't working. So post the error you get (including stack trace) instead of a auto configuration report (which isn't related to the error you get). Also post your `application.properties` .

Comment: I edited and attached more details. This is state without excluding.

Comment: There is no stack trace

Comment: Ok, it is: `No qualifying bean of type 'org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory`

Comment: Your question is making less and less sense and is becoming a mess. As stated don't randomly exclude auto configuration classes. What you have done now is disable my batis, so yes of course it will complain about those beans not being there (you disabled that!)>

Comment: Now it is not disabled.

Comment: There is already a bean named `sqlSessionFactory` hence it stops the auto config.

Comment: So, what should I do ? After all I must create sqlSessionFactory.

Comment: No you shouldn't... That is what the auto configuration is for.

Comment: `Parameter 0 of method sqlSessionFactory in org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
 - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'spring.datasource.type'
 - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager'`A

Comment: AS you can see, removing Bean sqlSessionFactore gives more errors

Comment: Which is the actual error. Firs tour configuration should be public and should ONLY be annotated with `@Configuration`. It should also be in the path that is scanned by your `Application` class if it isn't your configuration is pretty much useless.

Comment: Actual error is: `No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.` And after them I have these three errors as above. It is only @Configuraion annotated. Only Bean in this class is DataSource (on sqlSessionFactory). How to tell to spring to find other Configuration classess ? Thanks for your help

Comment: By either using `@Import` on your application class or by simply making sure it is in a package that is already scanned by the application class.

Comment: (Despite `@Configuration` it has also `@MapperScan`, but removing this doesnt help)

Comment: `@ComponentScan` contains configuration package, so it find it

Comment: Judging from your error it isn't. Where is your `@ComponentScan`. But if it also has `@MapperScan` (which isn't in the code here) the code you have isn't represented here...

Comment: `@ComponentScan` is in class with main function. I am following it: http://www.mybatis.org/spring/apidocs/reference/org/mybatis/spring/annotation/MapperScan.html

Comment: You are right.  I moved Bean for datasource to Application class - then it doesnt return error. `@Import` can't help. What should I do to force spring to respect other config classes ?

Comment: It already does, if it doesn't you must be doing something weird/flawed.

Comment: So where is the problem, that it can't see bean created in config class, although it can see it after moving bean to Applicaiton class ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have configured the following properties in `application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@db-host:port/catalog
    username: user
    password: pass
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Once you do that, you will be able to inject `DataSource` to a **sping component**;
as shown below.

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: On the whole, I have no `application.yml`, only `application.properties`.  Should I create it ? How to create it ?

Comment: Yea. You have create an application.properties and add the above configuration to it.